# Update row count in php mysqli not working when updating multiple query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update, rows-affected

Following is my code

```
//FIRST UPDATE QUERY
$firstupdatequery = "UPDATE `register` SET suser ='1' ";
//Second UPDATE QUERY
$updater = "UPDATE `register` SET suser ='$suser',steamleader ='$steamleader',ipdate ='$ipdate',customer ='$customer',cperson1 ='$cperson1',mobile1 ='$mobile1',phone ='$phone',fax ='$fax',email ='$email',website ='$website',pincode ='$pincode',state ='$state',city ='$city',address ='$address',status ='$status',data_resource ='$data_resource',comments ='$comments',data_status ='$data_status',followup_date ='$followup_date',last_followup_date ='$last_followup_date',last_comment ='$last_comment',data_assign ='$data_assign',bank_id = '$bank_id' WHERE id = ".$getid."";

$exequery = $conn->query($updater);
if($exequery){
  if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0){
    //insert for followup recored
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($conn);
    echo $conn->affected_rows;
    exit;
    //And than I am running another insert query here
```

this code shows if any row updated so i run the another insert query.but problem is when i press button without changing the any value still it mysqli object `affected rows` count to 1.

```
mysqli Object
(
    [affected_rows] => 1
```

Why this count to `1` even i didnt changed any value.
*

NOTE: i am Updating one row above this code

Comment: Do you get the same result when you do this with SQL alone (=> `ROW_COUNT()`)?

Comment: When i am echo update and perform it manually so it returns `0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0650 seconds.)`

Comment: MySQL is dumb. It's so dumb that it won't read the previous data values unless you tell it too. So every time you submit an `update` mysql gos to work and just says "yup boss, i took your data and i put it in, give me a treat because I did so with no errors". If you want update to only update if the data is different, then you'll need to compare your input to your data and act accordingly.

Comment: So what should i have to do

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick, I would call it a dirty one, but I know no cleaner way to do so

```
list($matched, $changed, $warnings) = sscanf($conn->info, "Rows matched: %d Changed: %d Warnings: %d");
```

Comment: You mean to say `[info] => Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1` Which returns by `mysqli Object`